# We have an issue with Preview in Wagtail CMS

Tags: preview, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

We have an issue with Preview in Wagtail CMS. I have looked around at several other people that have had this issue but none are the same as mine. As preview is not even working in Dev and we are receiving no errors to suggest what the issue might be.

We Use Wagtail 1.13.1 & DJANGO 1.11.8

When i click the preview button It just takes me to a new tab thats blank with no error or anything.

if i inspect the button I can see:

```html
<button class="button action-preview icon icon-view" data-action="/admin/pages/30/edit/preview/" data-auto-update="false">Preview</button>
```

So I took: /admin/pages/30/edit/preview/ and manually pasted into the browser and it gives me:

https://domain.dev:8000/admin/pages/30/edit/preview/

I am still receiving no errors, which leaves me to believe either a setting is incorrect or this is a bug in Wagtail as it does not work in Dev,Staging or Prod

If anyone can shed more light on this topic it would be greatly appreciated as at least if i got an error I could look to resolve it. but i get nothing.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I've had a similar issue in the past where there was an issue within the template or a middleware because something which is normally present when you render the page normally isn't when you render the page via preview. In order to get more information about the issue, you can try to: Make sure the log level is at least `INFO` (or `DEBUG` but it might get noisy) and click preview, open the debug console on the new tab and click preview again (this should refresh the preview tab and maybe show some JS errors?).

Comment: We have full debug on in dev so any errors usually show here. I actually think that this is a bug in the JS wagtail/wagtail/admin/static_src/wagtailadmin/js/page-editor.js around lines 344 - 419

Comment: A misconfigured ALLOWED_HOSTS setting is often the cause of preview issues, although that wouldn't usually surface in dev mode (assuming you're consistently using 'localhost'). I'd suggest starting from a fresh `wagtail start` project in development mode, and - assuming the preview error doesn't occur there - introduce configuration changes from your existing project one by one until you find one that triggers the failure. Then we can troubleshoot further...

Comment: FWIW, in `preview`, the `host` will be the one defined under `Settings > Sites` which might differs from what is listed in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, especially when you copy databases from an environment to another.